# Extracting important sub-sections and the sub set of documents associated with them from a set of documents

Tags: cluster-analysis, document, tf-idf

I have a set of documents all of which come under the category "crime".

Now, I want to categorize them into a number of (could be overlapping) clusters of documents where each of the clusters are formed under a sub-category like murder or kidnapping, etc.

I want to accomplish this using some way of identifying the importance of individual words occurring in each document. I have already tried using TF-IDF but it is not giving me satisfactory results.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to assign weights to frequently occurring words. Then you can group the words using a k-prototypes or the k-mode approach.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need supervision.

Words such as "suspect", "gun", are likely significant, but do not produce desirable categories. An unsupervised approach cannot know what a "kind of"crime is.